# MoonMail: No subscriber to attachSender

Tags: moonmail

When campaign sending process is fired up, AttachRecipientsService publish to SNS with the topic "ATTACH_SENDER_TOPIC_ARN". However, there is no subscriber to this action in AWS / MoonMail. Any idea how the "ATTACH_SENDER" is handled?

It is not possible to send a campaign without this information.

As noted here: https://github.com/microapps/MoonMail/wiki/Campaigns

> Users service will get the message and attach a sender object, with
>   the actual sender credentials in case he’s able to send the campaign
>   (pushing the message to the PrecompileCampaign topic), or will drop
>   the message to the campaign errors topic.

But there is no Users service. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced users service by sending a SNS event to the "PRECOMPILE_CAMPAIGN_TOPIC_ARN".

> events\lib\attach_recipients_count_service.js

```
 _publishToSns(canonicalMessage) {
        debug('= AttachRecipientsService._publishToSns', canonicalMessage);
        const params = {
          Message: JSON.stringify(canonicalMessage),
          TopicArn: process.env.PRECOMPILE_CAMPAIGN_TOPIC_ARN
        };
        return this.snsClient.publish(params).promise()
          .then(() => canonicalMessage);
      }
```

Make sure that the canonicalMessage contains "sender" object:

```
"sender": {
    "region": "...",
    "apiKey": "...",
    "apiSecret": "...",
    "ratePerSecond": "...",
    "emailAddress": "...",
    "fromName": "..."
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Users service is not open sourced, but you can take a look at the [sendTestCampaign](https://github.com/microapps/MoonMail/tree/master/api/campaigns/sendTestCampaign) function. If you provide it with a `campaign` and `sender` object it basically delivers an SNS message to the `PrecompileCampaign` topic straight away.

Comment: Would be nice to make this information available in your wiki :) https://github.com/microapps/MoonMail/wiki/Campaigns

Thank you for your help!